# Relocating layer's source file in QGIS

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to change the directory of a layer's source file without deleting and re-importing the layer?

Comment: Are you after any method (GUI/programmatically), and any version of QGIS?

Comment: Preferably GUI and latest version. I'll try romainbh's answer next time the issue presents itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with the plugin **Change datasource**, it's the easiest way to change the path of a layer in QGIS.

Copy the layer file (or multiples files in the case of a shapefile) into the new directory and then open your project and change the source with the plugin.

Comment: The plugin is a bit opaque to me. It asks for a string to be replaced with another string, but that does not seem to work. Any suggestions?  Do I need to really use this in QGIS.3.22? The Bad Layers handler launches in the beginning but does not seem to work for me, hence I went to this plugin...

Comment: UPDATE: I figured out that if I ignore QGIS' native "Handle Missing Layers" dialogue (click "Keep unavailable layers") and then go and 'fix' one of the layers that has a 'bad data source', the others also get fixed automatically. Rather counter-intuitive, but worked. (I did not use the plugin at all)